# Finding the Explicit formula for the $n$th term of series.

Tags: calculus

I'm given the series $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}$ and I want to write an explicit formula for the nth term.

As of right now I got the formula to be $1/(2*2^n)$ is there a way to write this in a more compact form so that it can be a geometric series? Thank you!

Comment: $a_n=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, n\in\Bbb N$

Answer (score 0):

your series is $$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+............$$
rewriting this series we have,$$\frac{1}{2^{1+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{2+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{3+1}}+.........$$
So from here the $n^{th}$ term of this series will be $$\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

Comment: ok. Would this be considered a geometric series?

Comment: or can I go about finding the explicit formula by factoring out the 1/4 and writing an equation with the 1/4 pulled out?

Comment: Yes this is a geometric series with conman ratio $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Yeah ! you can do but what I have given that is is much easier than this

Comment: alright. Since this is a geometric series I can find what it converges to by the formula a/1-r correct?

Comment: also how can I formally show the limit of this series? sorry for so many questions..

Comment: yes you can . and point of convergence will be $\frac{a}{1-r}$

Comment: best solution and very easy to understand

Comment: @Lil when you say prove formally do you mean by purely by the limit definition?